# How to fix this code so that it stops when the condition becomes true?

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I wrote the below code to estimate a specific value of epsilon and the code should stop the simulation when the condition becomes true (i.e. `w(t)-f < error`). Unfortunately the code didn't stop when the condition became true.

```
clear;clc;
tic
m=360;   n=20;  d=240;  l=240;error=1e-5;RF=1.8;erin=0;
error_alt=(5e-4)*180/pi;
deltheta=2*pi/m;    delz=1/n;
pin=0;f=1;
s=(d*d)/(l*l);
R=1/deltheta^2;
cor=(deltheta^2/delz^2)*s;
x=0:deltheta:2*pi;
y=0:delz:1;
iter=1000; 
sum=zeros(iter);
[epsilon]=0.01:0.01:0.9;
[theta]=0:deltheta:2*pi;
p0=zeros(m+1,n+1);
p=zeros(m+1,n+1);
cc=zeros(m+1,n+1);
mm=zeros(m+1,n+1);
wr=zeros(length(epsilon));
wt=zeros(length(epsilon));
w=zeros(length(epsilon));
for t=1:length(epsilon)
    h=zeros(m+1);
    p0=zeros(m+1,n+1);
    p=zeros(m+1,n+1);
    cc=zeros(m+1,n+1);
    mm=zeros(m+1,n+1);
    wt(t)=0;wr(t)=0;w(t)=0;
    phi1(t)=0;phi(t)=0;
    for i=1:m+1  
        h(i)=1+epsilon(t).*cos(theta(i));
    end
    sum(1)=0;
    phi1(t)=atan(sqrt(1.0-epsilon(t).^2)./epsilon(t));
    phi1(t)=m+1-(phi1(t)*180/pi);
    for k=1:iter
        sumij=0.0;
        at=round(phi1(t));
        for j=2:n
            for i=(at-9):(at+9);
                p0(i,j)=pin;
            end
        end
        for j=2:n
            p0(m+1,j)=p0(1,j);
        end
        for j=2:n
            for i=1:m
                if (i==1)
                    h1=1+epsilon(t).*cos(theta(i)+0.5*deltheta);
                    h2=1+epsilon(t).*cos(theta(i)-0.5*deltheta);
                    conh=h1-h2;
                    const=2*(1+cor)*R*h(i)^3;
                    A=3*h(i)^2*R*conh/const;
                    C=h(i)^3*R/const;
                    E=h(i)^3*R*cor/const;
                    G=-3*sqrt(R)*conh/const;
                    p(i,j)=(C+A/2)*p0(i+1,j)+(C-A/2)*p0(m,j)+E*(p0(i,j+1)+p0(i,j-1))+G;           
                else
                    conh=(h(i+1)-h(i-1))/2;
                    const=2*(1+cor)*R*h(i)^3;
                    A=3*h(i)^2*R*conh/const;
                    C=h(i)^3*R/const;
                    E=h(i)^3*R*cor/const;
                    G=-3*sqrt(R)*conh/const;
                    p(i,j)=(C+A/2)*p0(i+1,j)+(C-A/2)*p0(i-1,j)+E*(p0(i,j+1)+p0(i,j-1))+G;
                end
                if p(i,j)<0
                    p(i,j)=0.0;
                else
                    sumij=sumij+p(i,j);
                end
            end
        end
    for j=2:n
        p(m+1,j)=p(1,j);
    end
    for j=2:n
        for i=(at-9):(at+9)
            p(i,j)=pin;
        end
    end
    sum(k+1)=sumij;
    errorp=abs(sum(k+1)-sum(k))/abs(sum(k+1));
    if (errorp > error)
        for j=2:n
            for i=1:m
                p0(i,j)=RF*p(i,j)+(1-RF)*p0(i,j);
            end
        end
    else
    end
    end
    for j=2:n
        for i=2:m
            cc(i,j)=p(i,j).*sin(theta(i));  
            mm(i,j)=p(i,j).*cos(theta(i)); 
        end
    end
    wr(t)=trapz(y,trapz(x,cc));
    wt(t)=trapz(y,trapz(x,mm));
    w(t)=sqrt(wr(t).^2+wt(t).^2);
    phi(t) = atan2(wt(t), wr(t));
    phi(t)=m+1+(phi(t)*180/pi);
    erin=abs(phi(t)-phi1(t))/abs(phi(t));
    if (erin > error_alt)
        phi1=RF*phi+(1-RF)*phi1;
        at=round(phi1); 
    else
        if abs((w(t)-f)) < error
        break        
        end
    end
    if abs((w(t)-f)) < error
       epsilon(t)
       break        
    end
end
iterations=k;
itera=epsilon;
figure(1)
surf(p)
figure(2)
plot(p)
toc
```

Comment: Please shorten your code to a [mcve], i.e. delete all parts which are not relevant for the problem. Also, on which line is this code supposed to terminate?

Comment: See: [`while`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html)

Comment: Your code exceeds the range for floating point values, you are calculating with intermediate results which are lager than 10^600 resulting in `inf`. I can't imagine that's intended, there is probably a bug in your code.

Comment: @Daniel, it works correctly for a specific value of epsilon and the results are good, but when I make a range of epsilon and put the condition it doesn't work correctly and in the end it give results with (10E320), how can I fix that?

Comment: Is it intended that `w(t)` is `+inf`? I only ran two iterations of the outer loop.

Comment: it value must be about (0 ~ 3), if you remove the main loop (epsilon) and make the last if-condition (else; break), it will give a good result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the keywork [return](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/return.html?searchHighlight=return).

The difference between `break` and `return` is that

- [As said in the documentation](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html), `break` is used to exit a loop.
- `return` will exit the function.

Even thought `return` is built to exit functions, it also work in scripts.

So in your example, you should replace `break` by `return`

```
if abs((w(t)-f)) < error
    return       
end
```

Note that this keywork works no matter how deep you are in a nested loop. As an example :

```
for ii = 1:2
    for jj = 1:2
        for kk = 1:2
            disp(kk)
            return
        end
    end
end
```

> 1

while the `break` keyword will only end one loop :

```
for ii = 1:2 
    for jj = 1:2 
        for kk = 1:2
            disp(kk)
            break
        end 
    end 
end
```

> 1
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 1

Comment: While good general knowledge, the `break` statements in the provided code are not in a nested `for` loop.

Comment: @excaza It is in a not nested for loop (`for t=1:length(epsilon)`), which makes my answer the same. Did I understand badly the question then? It seems to me that the question ask to exit the code, and not only the loop